# Can't add reporting service component for MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssrs

Can't add reporting service component for MS SQL Server 2005

[image]

I want to reinstall sql server 2005, all components are disabled when i uninstall sql server 2005. It was bad than before now.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You don't have IIS installed: it's a pre-requisite and would have been shown on earlier setup screens:

[image]

Comment: yup, i've ran into this exact problem before.

Comment: My OS is Windows 7, and IIS was installed.

Comment: And can turn on IIS6 compatibility option.

Comment: I googled this question, some guys said installed SP3 may blocked add components. And I installed SP3 for SQL Server 2005.